# angular-cli + jenkins (ng test then build )

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, angular-cli

I want to use `ng test` + `ng build --prod` on Jenkins.

How I can use i. As I need to run build if a test is passed, without opening a browser.
Just want like:

```
ng test ? ng build --prod : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

solved:
in karma.config set params `singleRun: true`,
in package.json scripts write `ng test && ng build --prod`